# issue with some variables in a contact form

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to make functional my contact form using variables that I put in my setting on the admin panel. The variables work perfectly since I use them in other files but I can not make them functional in the contact form I do not know if they are correctly defined or I am calling them wrong. I am waiting for your help, I am new to the page, thank you.

PD: The form works perfectly if I enter the values manually for example if in $from I put $from = ''; Because it works without problems but with the variable no.

```
include "inc/database.php";

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `settings` LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $contactemail = $row['contactemail'];
    $adminemail = $row['adminemail'];
    $secretkey = $row['secretkey'];
    $website = $row['website'];

}
// require ReCaptcha class
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

// configure
$from = ''.$row['website'].' <'.$row['contactemail'].'>';
$sendTo = '<'.$row['adminemail'].'>';
$subject = 'New message from '.$row['website'].'';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Lastname', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
$recaptchaSecret = ''.$row['secretkey'].'';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot make the functional"? What debugging have you tried?

Comment: Well when it tried to send the form it gives me error I do not know if the variables are well put, I can not find the problem

Comment: The error will usually tell what the problem is. What was the error?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, and solve it. I was calling the variables as '. $row [' contactemail '] ;.' And just had to put them so $contacemail;

Same thanks anyway.